# Passing Variables to Smarty view file

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello I'm trying to send a value from my php file to tpl file.

when I print_r in php file I see my value is defined in array however when I print_r my tpl file I don't see this element.

```
 <img src="{$product.manufacturer_name}" alt="" title="" itemprop="image" />
```

and my controller

```
    $special = Product::getProducts((int)$this->langID , 0,6, 'name', 'DESC', 51);


                foreach ($special as $specia) 
                {
                    $id_image = Product::getCover($specia['id_product']);
    // get Image by id
                if (sizeof($id_image) > 0) 
                        {
                    $image = new Image($id_image['id_image']);

        // get image full URL
                        $image_url = _PS_BASE_URL_._THEME_PROD_DIR_.$image->getExistingImgPath()."-home_default.jpg";

                        $specia['manufacturer_name']=$image_url;   
                        }

                }

                $dir = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/ptspagebuilder/views/templates/front/widgets/sub/products.tpl';
$tdir = _PS_ALL_THEMES_DIR_ . _THEME_NAME_ . '/modules/ptspagebuilder/views/templates/front/widgets/sub/products.tpl';

                if (file_exists($tdir)) {
                    $dir = $tdir;
                }

    // get Product cover image (all images is possible retrieve by
    // Image::getImages($id_lang, $id_product) or
    // $productInstance->getImages($id_lang))




                $setting['product_tpl'] = $dir;
                $setting['products'] = $special;

                $output = array('type' => 'flashsale','data' => $setting);

                return $output;
            }
```

Comment: where exactly do you make print_r in your controller? do you have loop in tpl?

Comment: I put print_r in the last line of foreach and in view file I put print_r after foreach begins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$special` contain arrays, than you have mistake in script, change copies of vars in foreach loop. Try to change
`foreach ($special as $specia)` to `foreach ($special as $k=>$specia)`
`$specia['manufacturer_name']=$image_url;` to `$special[$k]['manufacturer_name']=$image_url;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't get your problem. You said that you assigned value in your php file but i can't see any value which is assigned. For assigning value in php file you have to assign value in smarty variable so that you can access it in your tpl file. For that you have to write code something like that:

In your controller first You have to assigned value like:

```
 $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'product' => $containing_product,
            ));
```

The $product contain the value which you want to access in your tpl file.

Now in your tpl file you can check it like:

```
{var_dump($product)}
```

And Now in your tpl file you can use that

```
<img src="{$product}" alt="" title="" itemprop="image" />
```